# How to change window manager to default?

Tags: window-manager, default, lxsession

I wanted to create a kiosk Ubuntu, then I followed this instruction: https://web.archive.org/web/20131210161955/http://phunehehe.is-great.org/2010/run-linux-with-a-bare-window-manager/

> Add a custom session by creating a file at /usr/share/xsessions/metacity-session.desktop. This file tells the
>   login manager about your session. 
>   content:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Encoding=UTF-8
Name=Metacity
Comment=Metacity without GNOME
Exec=/usr/local/bin/metacity-session
Type=Application
```

> Create the file to be executed by the session added in (1)
>   /usr/local/bin/metacity-session.content:

```
#!/bin/bash
if test -z "$DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS"; then
eval `dbus-launch --sh-syntax --exit-with-session`
fi
metacity --replace ccp & wmpid=$!
sleep 1
if [ -f ~/.metacity-session ]; then
source ~/.metacity-session &
else
xterm &
fi
# Wait for WM
wait $wmpid
```

> Create the user-specific config file ~/.metacity-session. This file will be
>   executed by the file added in (2). The content should be the program
>   you want to run, followed by an ampersand, for example

```
 firefox &
```

But when I did logout then wanted to login with metacity-session it didn't work(a black screen for a second and then back to login page again). Then I decided to restart my computer and then, I couldn't login even with my Ubuntu default desktop! Because when I try to login, after entering password and logging in, I have no menu and nothing! only default background pic shows and mouse pointer, nothing else!

Then I tried to install Putty on my other laptop with Win10, then connecting via SSH to Ubuntu laptop and remove all 3 files I did create before(3 files that the above instruction says). But nothing happened and I can not use my Ubuntu, because after logging in there is nothing! only background pic without any menu.

Answer (score 3):

We are running ubuntu 16.04 LTS. We are autostarting.   We want to start with the openbox window manager.  We have found that the window manager selection is stored in /var/lib/AccountsService/users/ubuntu.   Note: In my case ubuntu is the user name.

In this file we have:
    [User]
    Xsession=openbox
to start with the openbox window manager.

To start with the Unity window manager we have:
    [User]
    Xsession=ubuntu